# Get user list using Confluence prototype REST API

Tags: confluence

I have a prototype API which will return all the content from the confluence instance including users. The rest endpoint is **https://confluenceinstance.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/search.json?query=**

Is there a way I can get only the users in the system? I tried sending query=user which gave me irrelevant response. Any leads would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about hosted version of confluence, but in dedicated version you can download the Rest API Browser addon that would list all rest services and from there you can find that `user-management/1.0/users` returns a paginated list of users.